# Structure of make files for automatic installation

Tags: linux, make, makefile

We are doing one project and our contractor is taking care of installing all things required to install in linux.

he has make file for that.

That file is very big and he has used verious constants like this

```
BASE_DIR = "bla bla"
OTHER_DIR  = BASE_DIR/other
```

now each next constant defined is using the previous constant. and they are all over the place.

In the final function its very hard to decode which this install function is doing.

i have to search for that constant and then check all constants till top to figure out what installing command is doing.

I want to know that do all make files are like that. wont it be good to put all in one function for better readability

its very hard to read

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are quoting does not look like a correct makefile syntax.  Are you sure these come from a working makefile?

If the statements above did come from a working makefile, it would look like the person who wrote it did not do such a good job.